# SQL on multiple joins too slow

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, query-performance

I have trouble with very slow query. When I remove from query `activity_tracker` or `registration_statuses`, then is query faster (3-4 seconds).

activity_tracker - ~300 000rows

registration_statuses - ~300 000rows

users - ~32000rows

```
select users.name as 'Agent',
count(registration_statuses.id ) as 'Odoslané na DÚ',
count( registration_statuses.id ) as 'Uzatvorené',
count(activity_tracker.id) as 'Akcia vyhľadávania',
count(activity_tracker.id) as 'Otvorenie zložky',
count(activity_tracker.id) as 'Úprava/Uloženie zložky',
count(activity_tracker.id) as 'Zmena stavu zložky',
count(activity_tracker.id) as 'Pridanie aktualizácie zložky',
count(activity_tracker.id) as 'Pridanie poznámky zložky' 
from `users` 
left join `activity_tracker` on `users`.`id` = `activity_tracker`.`user_id` 
left join `registration_statuses` on `users`.`id` = `registration_statuses`.`created_by` 
inner join `role_user` on `users`.`id` = `role_user`.`user_id` 
where `role_user`.`role_id` <> 4 
  and (`registration_statuses`.`created_at` between '1970-01-01' and '2022-08-08') 
group by users.name
```

There is output from Explain

```
1   SIMPLE  role_user               range   PRIMARY,role_user_role_id_foreign           role_user_role_id_foreign                     4     NULL                95      Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using f...
1   SIMPLE  users                   eq_ref  PRIMARY                                     PRIMARY                                       4     role_user.user_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  registration_statuses   ref     registration_statuses_created_by_foreign    registration_statuses_created_by_foreign      5     role_user.user_id   1889    Using where
1   SIMPLE  activity_tracker        ref     activity_tracker_user_id_foreign            activity_tracker_user_id_foreign              4     role_user.user_id   3004    Using index
```

Comment: (1) The `left join`s are not necessary based on your filtering conditions.  (2) Which left join is causing the problem?

Comment: is the created_date condition working on registration_statuses ???
i believe mysql uses yyyy-mm-dd format..

Comment: @GordonLinoff I try with `join/inner join` same result. Problem is when I joining `activity_tracker` and `registration_statuses` at once. When I join only one of them i get result faster (3-4seconds).

Comment: @Shoaeb
My bad, yes format is bad but same result with yyyy-mm-dd and yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss too.

Comment: We need more information to help you. Please read this.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 It has a good section about query performance. Then please [edit] your question.

Comment: @Marek Adam How many rows in `role_user` table?

Comment: @MarekAdam is it possible use `group by users.id` ?

Comment: @ExploitFate `role_user` has 34 089 rows.
Yes is possible `group by users.id`

Answer (score 0):

Please test this query

```
SELECT 

id,
name AS 'Agent',
SUM(registration_statuses_value_1) AS 'Odoslané na DÚ',
SUM(registration_statuses_value_2) AS 'Uzatvorené',
SUM(activity_tracker_value_1) AS 'Akcia vyhľadávania',
SUM(activity_tracker_value_2) AS 'Otvorenie zložky',
SUM(activity_tracker_value_3) AS 'Úprava/Uloženie zložky',
SUM(activity_tracker_value_4) AS 'Zmena stavu zložky',
SUM(activity_tracker_value_5) AS 'Pridanie aktualizácie zložky',
SUM(activity_tracker_value_6) AS 'Pridanie poznámky zložky' 

FROM
(
    (
        SELECT 
            users.id,
            users.name, -- AS 'Agent',
            COUNT(registration_statuses.id) AS registration_statuses_value_1, -- 'Odoslané na DÚ',
            COUNT(registration_statuses.id) AS registration_statuses_value_2, -- 'Uzatvorené',
            0 AS activity_tracker_value_1, -- 'Akcia vyhľadávania',
            0 AS activity_tracker_value_2, -- 'Otvorenie zložky',
            0 AS activity_tracker_value_3, -- 'Úprava/Uloženie zložky',
            0 AS activity_tracker_value_4, -- 'Zmena stavu zložky',
            0 AS activity_tracker_value_5, -- 'Pridanie aktualizácie zložky',
            0 AS activity_tracker_value_6 -- 'Pridanie poznámky zložky' 
        FROM `users`
        LEFT JOIN `registration_statuses` ON `users`.`id` = `registration_statuses`.`created_by` 
        INNER JOIN `role_user` ON `users`.`id` = `role_user`.`user_id` 
        WHERE `role_user`.`role_id` <> 4 AND (`registration_statuses`.`created_at` BETWEEN '1970-01-01' AND '2022-08-08') 
        GROUP BY users.id
    )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT
            users.id,
            users.name, -- AS 'Agent',
            0 AS registration_statuses_value_1, -- 'Odoslané na DÚ',
            0 AS registration_statuses_value_2, -- 'Uzatvorené',
            count(activity_tracker.id) AS activity_tracker_value_1, -- 'Akcia vyhľadávania',
            count(activity_tracker.id) AS activity_tracker_value_2, -- 'Otvorenie zložky',
            count(activity_tracker.id) AS activity_tracker_value_3, -- 'Úprava/Uloženie zložky',
            count(activity_tracker.id) AS activity_tracker_value_4, -- 'Zmena stavu zložky',
            count(activity_tracker.id) AS activity_tracker_value_5, -- 'Pridanie aktualizácie zložky',
            count(activity_tracker.id) AS activity_tracker_value_6 -- 'Pridanie poznámky zložky' 
        FROM `users` 
        LEFT JOIN `activity_tracker` ON `users`.`id` = `activity_tracker`.`user_id` 
        LEFT JOIN `registration_statuses` ON `users`.`id` = `registration_statuses`.`created_by` 
        INNER JOIN `role_user` ON `users`.`id` = `role_user`.`user_id` 
        WHERE `role_user`.`role_id` <> 4 AND (`registration_statuses`.`created_at` BETWEEN '1970-01-01' AND '2022-08-08') 
        GROUP BY users.id
    )
) AS `d`
GROUP BY `id`
```

**UPD**: Replace last join by sub-query

```
SELECT `users`.`name` AS 'Agent',
COUNT( `registration_statuses`.`id` ) AS 'Odoslané na DÚ',
COUNT( `registration_statuses`.`id` ) AS 'Uzatvorené',
COUNT( `activity_tracker`.`id` ) AS 'Akcia vyhľadávania',
COUNT( `activity_tracker`.`id` ) AS 'Otvorenie zložky',
COUNT( `activity_tracker`.`id` ) AS 'Úprava/Uloženie zložky',
COUNT( `activity_tracker`.`id` ) AS 'Zmena stavu zložky',
COUNT( `activity_tracker`.`id` ) AS 'Pridanie aktualizácie zložky',
COUNT( `activity_tracker`.`id` ) AS 'Pridanie poznámky zložky' 
FROM `users` 
LEFT JOIN `activity_tracker` ON `users`.`id` = `activity_tracker`.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN `registration_statuses` ON `users`.`id` = `registration_statuses`.`created_by` 
WHERE 
  `registration_statuses`.`created_at` BETWEEN '1970-01-01' AND '2022-08-08'
  AND `users`.`id` IN (SELECT `user_id`  FROM `role_user` WHERE `role_id` <> 4 )
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
```

Comment: Not working too, script is running over minute and still not end like in my example.

Comment: @MarekAdam I've updated the answer. Could you check query with sub-query?